# Why the ReentrantLock can't get the lock

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple program to test the Condition as below:

```
public class ThreadTest2 {
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    public void conditionWait() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("1");
            condition.await();
            System.out.println("2");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void conditionSignal() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println("3");
            condition.signal();
            System.out.println("4");
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadTest2 test = new ThreadTest2();

        test.conditionWait();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        test.conditionSignal();
    }
}
```

The result is: 1,
it seems like that conditionWait() method has taken the lock, so the conditionSignal() method cann't get it. While, if I change the program to use thread in each method like that:

```
public class ThreadTest2 {
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    public void conditionWait() throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    System.out.println("1");
                    condition.await();
                    System.out.println("2");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            };
        }.start();
    }

    public void conditionSignal() throws InterruptedException{
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    System.out.println("3");
                    condition.signal();
                    System.out.println("4");
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            };
        }.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadTest2 test = new ThreadTest2();

        test.conditionWait();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        test.conditionSignal();
    }
}
```

The result is：1 3 4 2， so what's the difference between them, why using thread can get the lock, while without thread cann't

Comment: Because locks and conditions are designed to work **between** threads. In your first test there is only **one** thread. How is that ever going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `conditionWait` you take the lock and **wait** for the condition. This does indeed temporarily release the lock **but it still waits** possibly forever.

The only way for the `wait` to complete would be for the condition to be signalled. Where would the signal come from if you are waiting? Only from **another thread**. But there is **no other thread** so this will wait forever.

Comment: emm, I'm still puzzle about why lock.lock(); can work for different threads, in second test, it can get the lock, but in first test, it cann't

Comment: in second test, the thread in conditionWait() execute lock.lock to get the lock and doesn't release it while waiting, why the thread in conditionSignal() can execute lock.lock again to get the lock

Comment: @gesanri - In the first test the code never proceeds past `condition.await();` so `condition.signal();` will never be called because it is called in `conditionSignal()` and the **one** thread cannot get there because it is waiting for the condition.

Comment: @gesanri - In the second test `conditionWait()` takes the lock and waits for the signal. Meanwhile, **in another thread** `conditionSignal()` gets called releasing the `wait`. Note that `condition.await()` releases the lock before waiting so other threads can take the lock before signaling.